# What is a good way in Odoo 16 to format currency or money in a Python module?

Tags: python, odoo-16

I have a module where I am trying to present the user with a friendly error message. Is there a way to do this in Odoo?

```py
# Check if the order value matches the Easy Credit order value
ecOrderValue = client.response.json().get('orderDetails').get('originalOrderValue')
if ecOrderValue != self.sale_order.amount_total:
    errors.append((_('EasyCredit and order total mismatched! EasyCredit: %s - Order: %s') % (
        ecOrderValue, self.sale_order.amount_total)))
```

I tried `locale` and `Monetary` but `locale` just shows an error saying C is not a valid locale. `Monetary` converts to HTML but I just want a string.